# Allowing all apps/users access to folder - S3FS-FUSE

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3fs

I'm running an application on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance, here's what I've done:
- I've mounted S3 bucket as folder with s3fs-fuse using this command (unfortunately as root : sudo):

```
sudo s3fs your_bucketname /mys3bucket -o use_cache=/tmp -o allow_other -o uid=1001 -o mp_umask=002 -o multireq_max=5 -o use_path_request_style -o url=https://s3-{{aws_region}}.amazonaws.com
```

regarding the uid=1001 and mp_unmask=002 and multireq_max=5

I've just copied them from instructions, but I have access to the mounted folder and works as expected

- I've set the permissions for the mounted folder to 777
- From the terminal (using sudo) I have full access to the folder that i have mounted the S3 bucket to, I can read and write, edit and delete

But I've expected that all users would have access to the folder because again the folder has 777 permissions and I've mounted the S3 bucket with -o allow_other
But this doesn't seem to be the case, the applications that I install don't seem to be able to access the folder.

The issue was detected when an application on a docker container couldn't access the folder, although when I ssh into the container as root user, I have full access to the folder.

But then when I've installed applications directly on the Ubuntu instance, the application still couldn't access the folder.
Even when I run the application with sudo

I came to the conclusion that it's s3fs issue.
What would help give my applications permission to access to the said folder?